# Удаление элемента из массива по индексу

Tags: java

```
public class DataContainer<T> {
    T[] data;
    DataContainer(T[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public int add(T item) {
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < data.length ; i++) {
                if (item == null) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (data[i] == null) {
                    data[i] = item;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if (data.length >1&&data[i-1] != item) {
                data = Arrays.copyOf(data,data.length+1);
                data[i] = item;
        }
        if (data.length ==1&&data[i-1] != item ) {
                data = Arrays.copyOf(data,data.length+1);
                data[i] = item;
        }
        if (data.length==0) {
            data = Arrays.copyOf(data,1);
            if (data[i] != item ) {
                data[i] = item;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    public T[] getItem() {
        return data;
    }
    public T get(int index) {
        if (data.length <=index) {
            return null;
        }
       return data[index] ;
    }
    public boolean delete(int index) {
        for (int i = index; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] == data[index]) {
                for (int j = index; j < data.length; j++) {
                    data[i] = data[j];
                }
            }
            data = Arrays.copyOf(data,data.length -1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

MAIN 

public class DataContainerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataContainer<Integer> dc = new DataContainer<>(new Integer[]{1,2,3});
        System.out.println(dc.add(5));
        System.out.println(dc.delete(1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dc.getItem()));

    }
}
```

При удаление, например в массив с данными - 1,2,3 добавляю 5, а затем удаляю элемент по индексу 1, и тогда должно получится - 1,3,5, но получается 1,5,3 и всегда два последних элемента меняются местами. Почему?

Comment: Не проще ли использовать `IntStream`? Версия `Java` какая?

Comment: Точнее даже, добавленная 5 становится на позицию удаленного элемента. А если не добавлять 5, то последний индекс заменяет удаленный элемент.

Comment: @gregzakharov Нельзя использовать stream api

Comment: Вы бы не могли тогда дополнить свой вопрос конкретизирующими правками?

Comment: Ну вот Вы создали Ваш контейнер. Выведите его, чтобы убедится, что он соответствует Вашим ожиданиям. Добавили что-то - опять выведите. Вместо того, чтобы сидеть и в носу ковырять.

Comment: Почему при удалении нельзя сделать второй массив, длиной на 1 элемент короче, а затем просто циклом скопировать туда элементы первого массива, пропуская удаляемый элемент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю что вы там так сложно делаете, но добавление это просто увеличить размер массива на +1 и записать новый элемент в последнее место.

```
public int add(T item) {
  data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length + 1);
  data[data.length - 1] = item;
  return data.length - 1; // always last?
}
```

Удаление тоже ничего сложного (без проверки попадания в массив), сдвиг влево и обрезать массив.

```
public boolean delete(int index) {
  for (int i = index + 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i - 1] = data[i];
  }
  data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length - 1);
  return true; // false if out of bounds?
}
```

Comment: Действительно просто, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я совершенно не понимаю, что это тут делает.

```
if (data[i] == data[index]) {
```

---

Что делает этот цикл?

```
            for (int j = index; j < data.length; j++) {
                data[i] = data[j];
            }
```

Я Вам скажу, что он делает. Пишет одно за другим несколько значений в одно и то же место. Вы можете человеческими словами описать, что Вы хотите здесь сделать?

---

> чтобы элементы оставались под своими индексами

А в том месте, где находится удаляемый элемент, что должно оказаться? Ну, напишите

```
data[index] = null;
```

и все.

Comment: Мне требуется удалить элемент передаваемый в index. Например у меня массив - [1,2,3]. Я вызываю delete(1), который удаляет элемент по индексу 1, то есть в данном случае - 2. И при выводе массива должно получится 1,3. Но получается, что последний элемент заменяет удаленный. Я понимаю, что это из-за цикла, поэтому и хочу узнать, как сделать так, чтобы элементы оставались под своими индексами. У меня получилось с двумя массива, но в данный момент я не хочу создавать дополнительный массивы и сделать все с одним.

Comment: @Charismatic Это не человеческий язык, а черт знает что. Какой должен быть результат удаления элемента?

Comment: Массив - [*,*,*,*....]. Удаляем элемент(индекс любой).  Получаем массив без удаленного элемента, как я указал выше, массив [1,2,3], delete(1), получаем [1,3]. В моём случае  я получаю [3,1].

Comment: @Charismatic "В моём случае я получаю [3,1]." - Не может быть.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем весь этот код? Достаточно двух строчек

```java
Integer[] array = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int index = 1;

Integer[] result = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length - 1);
System.arraycopy(array, index + 1, result, index, array.length - index - 1);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Получаем на выходе

> [ 1, 3, 4, 5 ]

Comment: Работа только с массивом, с Collection работать нельзя.

Comment: @Charismatic что то я не вижу этого требования в условиях задачи